# Does delete free the space allocated by vectors in an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose I create an array of vectors, and then I allocate memory for `num_vectors` many vectors.
What happens when `delete` gets executed after making some `push_back` operations in random vector elements? I wonder if all the allocated memory (by `new` and `push_back`) gets freed.

```cpp
int num_vectors = 123456;
std::vector<uint64_t>* arr_vecs;
arr_vecs = new std::vector<uint64_t>[num_vectors];

int random_ix;
int random_val = 999;

random_ix = 1;
arr_vecs[random_ix].push_back(random_val);

random_ix = 88;
arr_vecs[random_ix].push_back(random_val);

random_ix = 123;
arr_vecs[random_ix].push_back(random_val);

delete[] arr_vecs;
```

The question is not about good/bad practices in modern C++. I rather ask a specific question.

It seems like it gets freed, however I would like to have a better intuition about the expected behavior.

Comment: When you execute `delete[] arr_vecs`, you are deallocating the memory that was previously allocated for the array of vectors. This will free the memory associated with each vector within the array, including the elements that were added through push_back operations. Running a tool like `valgrind` would show all the memory leaks, if any

Comment: when you `delete[]` the destrructor for each and every element in the array will be called.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>>`?

Comment: Addendum 1: If the destructor for all of the elements executes, than means the constructor must have executed for all of the elements when the array was created.  This means if you do not have a default constructor for the array elements you have to take some extra and very interesting steps to make an array. Addendum 2: freed memory doesn't necessarily go anywhere any time soon. You may not see any change in the program's allocated storage, and you may be able to write through a "dangling" reference into ghost-of-object without an immediately detectable error.

Comment: what optimization-related reason?

Comment: @bocebir -- *there is an optimization-related reason* -- `arr_vecs = new std::vector<uint64_t>[num_vectors];` -- You are mistaken if you believe this is more efficient than `std::vector<std::vector<uint64>> vecs(num_vectors)`.

Comment: @bocebir `T* var = new T[x];...stuff... delete [] var;`  It doesn't matter what `T` is.  This *must* work correctly, otherwise `T` is broken and cannot be used reliably.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The smart-collection (RAII) equivalent is `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<uint64_t>[]>`, and it does make more efficient use of memory than vector-of-vector.

Comment: If you really want efficiency you may wanna pre allocate all you need in your program in one go with virtualalloc and mange the memory pool yourself. @BenVoigt

Comment: I'm not sure how "optimization" factors in here as you're already using `std::vector`, just in a very odd way. Once you go down the road of allocation with `new[]` you expose yourself to a lot of memory management overhead that can be avoided with a container, even a `unique_ptr` as Ben points out. If you're upset about people trying to help on a site *explicitly about helping people*, you're going to have to take it in stride.

Comment: 99.9% of the time when someone's using C++ in a bizarre way it's from a lack of understanding a better way. I'm still not convinced this isn't the case, but if you're happy with the answer here, and it gets you where you want to go, so be it.

Comment: @Shahrooz: Using `VirtualAlloc` for a single array is incredibly inefficient.  Building your own heap data structure.... yes you can match the efficiency of `new[]` at the cost of a huge amount of effort.  Or you can skip all that and just use `std::make_unique<T[]>(size)`, which gets you the same efficiency as `new[]` with automatic cleanup.

Comment: I said "pre allocate all the memory you think you'll be needing in your program in one go", not for just one vector, dude @BenVoigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, the delete operator will call the array's object destructors and in the std::vector destructor the memory that the vector has allocated is freed.

```
arr_vecs = new std::vector<uint64_t>[num_vectors];
//will create "num_vectors" of vectors calling default constructor for each 
delete[] arr_vecs;
//calls delete on each newed object which calls the destructor of the object
```

it is advised to use a vector of vectors if you need multidimensional arrays, or you could create a 1D array and map your N-D array to 1D by simple math.